# Trying to implement Albers projection in Python, what is going wrong?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyproj

I have a platform where I can't import Proj4. I only need to convert points to Albers projection, so it seemed simple, but my conversion has some errors:

Projection definition: `+proj=aea +lat_1=52 +lat_2=64 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=105 +x_0=18500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +units=m +towgs84=28,-130,-95,0,0,0,0 +no_defs'`

Here's the code implemented from the [formulae on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection):

[image]

```
from math import sin, radians, cos

def albers_proj(lon0, fi0, fi1, fi2, R=6367444.5, x0=0):
    lon0, fi0, fi1, fi2 = [radians(i) for i in (lon0, fi0, fi1, fi2)]

    n = (sin(fi1) + sin(fi2)) / 2
    C = cos(fi1) ** 2 + 2 * n * sin(fi1)
    ro0 = R / n * (C - 2 * n * sin(fi0)) ** .5
    def transformer(lon, lat):
        lon, lat = radians(lon), radians(lat)
        ro = R / n * (C - 2 * n * sin(lat)) ** .5
        theta = n * (lon - lon0)

        return ro * sin(theta) + x0, ro0 - ro * cos(theta)

    return transformer

albers_siberia = albers_proj(105, 0, 52, 64, R=6367444.5, x0=18500000)
print(albers_siberia(83, 55))
```

Output:

```
(17127237.118954152, 5777762.666018201)
```

I found the best R to minimise the error, but still something is not right:

```
    wgs84: 83.0 55.0

r = 6356302.97445488

     qgis: 17121825.913615   5767652.8720776
my script: 17129639.13010738 5767652.944553478
    error:     7813.21649238       0.072475878
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These formulas are for the Sphere, but are using an ellipsoid in the Proj4 string : `+ellps=krass`.

Comment: Formulas for the ellipsoid can be found at page 101 of [this working manual](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf) on USGS.

Comment: @FSimardGIS post this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formulae you have used are for the spherical case. However, your proj4 string indicates that you are using an ellipsoid (`+ellps=krass`). In order to get the proper results on the ellipsoid, you will have to implement the ellipsoidal formulae.

These formulae can be found in [this working manual](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf) from USGS at page 101. The parameters for different ellispoids (semi-major, semi-minor axis, flattening) can be found in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_ellipsoid#Historical_Earth_ellipsoids).